# Combine multiple rows of lists into one big list using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with multiple lists. Is there any way to combine all of the lists from all rows ( there could be 100 rows ) into one big list?

```
     fruits
0    [apple, banana, orange]
1    [berry, lemon]
2    [apple, tomato]
3    [lime, orange, banana]
```

Expected Output

```
[ 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'berry', 'lemon', 'apple', 'tomato', 'lime', 'orange', 'banana' ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `df.explode()`

```
lst = df['fruits'].explode().to_list()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df["fruits"].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try extend :

```
result = []
for row in fruits :
    result.extend(row)
```